# Stack Widget with Google Maps and Container on it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I have a Stack Widget and the widgets inside the Stackis a Google Maps Map and on it a Container.

When i scroll and reach the container while scrolling it ignores the scroll gesture.

```
return mapsService.loading
    ? Loading()
    : Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: GoogleMap(
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(mapsService.markers.values),
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: mapsService.cameraPosition,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              mapsService.controller.complete(controller);
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation:
            FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor:
              mapsService.dangerLevel[mapsService.currentDanger],
          child: const Icon(Icons.warning),
          onPressed: () {
            print("FLOATINGACTIONBUTTON GEDRÜCKT!");
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                      value: MapsService(), child: HelpCallAlertDialog());
                });
          },
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.swap_horizontal_circle),
                onPressed: () {
                  mapsService.changeDangerLevel();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(mapsService.helpCallsCount.toString()),
                onPressed: () async {
                  mapsService.getHelpCallSize();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      HelpCallCard(),
      ],
    );
```

HelpCallCard class

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: mapsService.helpCalls,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

      return Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children:
              snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return IgnorePointer(
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Text(document.data["latitude"].toString()),
                  Text("Faszinierend!"),
                ],),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      );
    });
```

}

I want the HelpCallCards on my google Maps, i can see them. But its blocking the Google Maps ui from scrolling when my fingure touches it

Comment: share some code.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is a bid old, but my answer may help others.

I had a similar issue using the Mapbox library instead of Google Maps. My workaround was to define manually the Container Height, and make sure that my foreground container was not taking all the space on the screen.

```
return new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Container(
      height: 1000, // This line solved the issue
      child: FullMapPage(), // Mapbox
    ),
    new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: FirestoreSlideshow(), // My cards showing in front of the Map's
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thx for sharing,will help for sure!